# Creating slider objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple job to do. I am creating JQuery sliders dynamically. I don't know how many number of sliders the page may have.

```
for (j=1;j<3;j++){

    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.id='rg'+j;
    newdiv.className="rg-gallery";

    document.getElementById('newval').value="$('#"+newdiv.id+"')";
    var newid=document.getElementById('newval').value; 

    // gallery container
    $rgGallery          = newid,
    // carousel container
    $esCarousel         = $rgGallery.find('div.es-carousel-wrapper'),
    // the carousel items
    $items              = $esCarousel.find('ul > li'),
    // total number of items
    itemsCount          = $items.length;
    ..........................
}
```

Where `newval` is an input box...The above code doesn't work but then I give 
          `$rgGallery = $('#rg2')`, **it works**
the variable at the end gets the same value i.i `var newid=$('rg2');`

Comment: Where's the question? What happens? What's not happening? ....

Comment: $rgGallery = newid --> this doesn't work.. if the id is passed directly it works..  newdiv.id='rg'+j; -->> this is the statement that is creating the id's

Comment: If the code you provided is within a function, remember to declare `j` with the `var` keyword to prevent polluting the global namespace :)